# External JavaScript dependency with Bower

Tags: javascript, elixir, jquery-select2, bower, phoenix-framework

I have a nearly-vanilla Phoenix setup in which I want to use select2[1]. I have bootstrap and jquery configured by means of bower. The front-end is bootstrap 4 and it all works great, so that's covered. See my bower config below.

The steps I tried are the following.

1. I have created a minimal working example in HTML from the website of select2, and included the js and css via a CDN. This all worked.
2. I have installed `select2` via `npm` using `npm install --save select2`.
3. I have verified that the select2 data is present in my `http://localhost:8000/js/app.js`.
4. I have added the script needed to execute select2 on the option list (see below). I have added this below my import of app.js.

When I navigate to the page I have the minimal working example on (the homepage), I see this error in the console:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).select2 is not a function @http://0.0.0.0:4000/:85:9
mightThrow@http://0.0.0.0:4000/js/app.js:7638:21
resolve/</process<@http://0.0.0.0:4000/js/app.js:7706:12
 undefined jquery.js:3822
[Show/hide message details.] TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function[Learn More]
```

I admit, I have no clue how this all works, as my knowledge is all focussed on backend related tasks. The entire codebase is on github as well [2].

Any help would be appreciated.

## Relevant part of app.html.eex

```
   <script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    });
   </script>
```

## Html added to layout.html.eex

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

## brunch-config.js

```
exports.config = {
  // See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files: {
      javascripts: {
          joinTo: "js/app.js"
      },
      stylesheets: {
          joinTo: "css/app.css",
          order: {
              after: ["css/app.css"] // concat app.css last
          }
      },
      templates: {
          joinTo: "js/app.js"
      }
  },

  conventions: {
      assets: /^(static)/
  },

  // Phoenix paths configuration
  paths: {
      // Dependencies and current project directories to watch
      watched: ["static", "css", "js", "vendor", "scss", "fonts"],
      // Where to compile files to
      public: "../priv/static"
  },

  // Configure your plugins
  plugins: {
      babel: {
          // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
          ignore: [/vendor/]
      },
      sass: {
          native: true,
          options: {
              includePaths: ["node_modules/bootstrap/scss", "node_modules/font-awesome/scss"], // Tell sass-brunch where to look for files to @import
              precision: 8 // Minimum precision required by bootstrap-sass
          }
      },
      copycat: {
        "fonts" : ["static/fonts", "node_modules/font-awesome/fonts"],
        verbose : false, //shows each file that is copied to the destination directory
        onlyChanged: true //only copy a file if it's modified time has changed (only effective when using brunch watch)
      }
  },

  modules: {
      autoRequire: {
          "js/app.js": ["js/app"]
      }
  },

  npm: {
      enabled: true,
      globals: {
          select2: 'select2',
          $: 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery',
          Tether: 'tether',
          Popper: "popper.js",
          bootstrap: 'bootstrap'
      }
  }
};
```

[1] https://select2.org/
[2] https://github.com/m1dnight/gymlog/tree/frontend_crap

Comment: is your $document.ready call below your <script src="/js/app.js"> tag?

Comment: Yes it is. Will add snippet.

Comment: I don't know select2, but as far as I can see, it registers itself on the `$` or `jQuery` object, so you can use `$('...').select2()` on an element. The problem is that at the time you call the function it is not yet registered on the `$` object. You could try to move your call into `app.js` after you know it is registered.